How can you specify a type for a type parameter inside square brackets?
Why is this notation a parsing error, or what should I be doing instead? I'm trying to pass the string type to Foo.myFunc.
type Foo = {
  myFunc <T> (): T
}

type stringFunc = Foo['myFunc']<string> // Parsing error: ';' expected

This gives me what I want, but is gross.
declare const foo: Foo
type stringFunc = typeof foo.myFunc<string>


foo.myFunc<string> is an instantiation expression, and you cannot write instantiation expressions purely at the type level, see this comment. "Gross" is your only choice without some other refactoring (like moving T outside of the scope of myFunc, which changes the meaning).

Note that this has little to do with "square brackets".  You have the same problem with type MyFunc = {<T>(): T}; type StringFunc = MyFunc<string>; // error.

The issue is that TypeScript doesn’t support applying type arguments directly in an indexed access type like Foo['myFunc']<string>.
To solve this:

Use a utility type to extract the return type:
type MyFuncReturn<T> = Foo['myFunc'] extends (...args: any[]) => T ? T : never;
type StringFunc = MyFuncReturn<string>;


Or, use typeof with an instance:
declare const foo: Foo;
type StringFunc = ReturnType<typeof foo.myFunc>;



This avoids the parsing error and binds the generic type correctly.

I'm trying to get the type type stringFunc = () => string in this case. Is typeof the only way then? I also tried type myFunc = Foo['myFunc']; type stringFunc = myFunc<string>;, but that doesn't work either.

That utility type is just passing through T from input to output. It doesn't instantiate a type parameter in a generic function. That is, it only works for functions whose return types are the same as their generic type parameter, meaning you might as well write type MyFuncReturn<T> = T. I'm not sure I see a point to such a utility type. I guess if you passed in something wrong you'd get never, but that looks like the job of a constraint, not a type function. I'm confused how that approach addresses the question.
